# Stream content to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, nio

I would like to upload a large `Set<Integer>` to Google Cloud Storage. I can do that with:

```
Blob result = storage.create(blobInfo, Joiner.on('\n').join(set).getBytes(UTF_8));
```

But this will create an intermediate String with all the content that might be too large.
I found an [example](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#writer-com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobWriteOption...-) with `WriteChannel.write()`:

```java
 Set<Integer> set = ...
 String bucketName = "my-unique-bucket";
 String blobName = "my-blob-name";
 BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
 byte[] content = Joiner.on('\n').join(set).getBytes(UTF_8);
 BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
 try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
     writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content, 0, content.length));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
   // handle exception
 }
```

However, if I do that, the entire `set` is converted to a String and then to `byte[]`. The String itself might be too big.

Is there an example how to iterate over the set and transform it to a ByteBuffer? or should I do a loop on chunks of the set?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "it doesn't show how to iterate the bytes".  Maybe you could edit the question to show the code you have so far, and what specifically you are stuck with or isn't working the way you exepect.  It's generally not difficult in java to read and write data between channels.  If you have a question about the java channel API, then you should focus your question on that.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. I am not sure if I am looking for a different GCP api or different NIO api.

Comment: Seems like your problem is that `Joiner.on('\n').join(set)` returns the full byte array in memory.  If you want to stream the source data, you'll need an API that streams the byte content instead of returning everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach I could think of would be:

```
 try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
   for(Integer val : set) {
     String valLine = val.toString() + '\n';
     writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(valLine.getBytes(UTF_8));
   }
 }
```

Mind you, this isn't very efficient. It creates a lot of small ByteBuffers. You could greatly improve on this by writing into a single larger ByteBuffer and periodically calling writer.write with it.

Comment: Thanks, this with `Iterators.partition` looks better.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating an intermediate String with all the bytes you can upload from a file. You can find example code to do an upload from a file in various languages [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample).

Comment: upload from a file does not help because I want to upload directly from the set.